# Using LinkedHashMap for adding selected items in h:selectManyListbox

Tags: jsf

I am working on a JSF application. I have used new LinkedHashMap to retrieve two column values from a table of database to populate a listbox. First column contains the Item and second column contains the Price. The items are displaying in my listbox, but when I select one or two of the items and clicked the button calculate, its gives me error. The error is

> javax.faces.FacesException: Target model Type is no a Collection or Array

See my code below **Java**:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ListBox";
String user = "root";
String pw = "root";

String favlst;
double total;
double price;
String item;
Map<String,Object> lst; {
    try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM list";
Statement stt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery(sql);

lst = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
while(rs.next()){
     price = rs.getDouble("Price");
     item = rs.getString("Item");
    lst.put(item, price);
}

}catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public Map<String, Object> getSelectlst() {
    return lst;
}

public String Calculate(){
    total = 0;
    price = 0;
    total += (Double)lst.get(item);
return "success";
   }
 }
```

**JSF**

```
<h:form>
    <h3> Generated by Map </h3>

    <h:selectManyListbox value = "#{menu2.selectlst}">
        <f:selectItems value = "#{menu2.selectlst}"/>
    </h:selectManyListbox>  

    <br> <br>

    <h:commandButton value = "Calculate" action = "#{menu2.Calculate}"/>
    <br> <br>
Total: Rs <h:outputLabel value = "#{menu2.total}"></h:outputLabel>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that you use the same property in the value attribute of the `f:selectItems` en `h:selectManyListbox`. That must not be right. And if you look at the LinkedHasMap api, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html, the error  is very clear. Change the property behind the value of the selectManyListbox to one that is of the correct type.

Comment: Please correct my code :(

Comment: All the info is in there. If you want a fully prepared example, wait for someone with more time and a real computer. I don't have the time nor the urge nor the material (a mobile phone) to help further, sorry.

Comment: and btw, the title is not in line with the problem. Since the items **are** displayed and hence the mysql tag is 'wrong' (as is the java tag)

Comment: How do I calculate the price of items selected ?

Comment: Sorry, seriously…  first of all is this comment totally unrelated to your original question and this answer and secondly it is **soooooo** basic that if you  are uncapable of just doing it or  finding (e.g. via a search engine) how to do this in java, I'd go searching for q different job…  sorry to be so blunt. Please flag this comment if you want